# Confiure trix editor to not generate header style tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-security-policy, trix

I am using 'trix-rails' gem in a Ruby on Rails project. I need to make the project abide to no unsafe-inline CSP, but I have problems with the two style tags generated by trix in the header.

I am using trix-rails as per the instructions:

```
...
//= require trix
//= require_tree .
...
```

... in my assets/javascript/application.js

I think that triggers the following file's execution: https://github.com/basecamp/trix/blob/custom-elements-v1/src/trix/core/helpers/custom_elements.coffee, which inserts two inline style tags into the DOM:

[style tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1z0e.png)

Now I know that the latest version of trix-editor comes with the capability of addinga nonce to these tags, but unfortunately trix-rails uses v.1.3.1.
There is the possibility of introducing ActionText but I'd like to keep code changes (and database changes) to the minimum.

I have extracted the css to a seperate file but cannot get rid of the tags. There was a suggestion to use Trix.config for that but I can't figure out how to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'd advise you to move away from using the trix-rails gem, but use a more modern way of including javascript dependencies that don't make you dependent on an outdated gem. The latest rails either uses importmaps (more web native) or bundling (more compact, better control over what code is sent): https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding trix@2.0.10 to package.json, removing the `//= require trix` line from assets/javscripts/application.js and adding `import Trix from 'trix'` to javascript/packs/application.js and it works fine.

PS. @murb, We use both ways for there's too much legacy code depending on old gems, unfortunately.